# How to fix the error "the left hand side of an arithematic operation must be of type 'any' 'number' 'bigint' or enum type' using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi i want to fix error "the left hand side of an arithematic operation must be of type 'any' 'number' 'bigint' or enum type" using react and typescript.

what i am trying to do?

i have code below,

```
 const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState<any>(undefined);

 const {
     data: dataProgress,
 } = useProgress({
     variables: { id },
     fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
 });


 React.useEffect(() => {
     if (status === EnumStatus.INITIAL || status === EnumStatus.FINISHED || status 
         === EnumStatus.FAILED) {
             setProgress(undefined);
     }
     if (status === EnumStatus.STARTED) {
         setProgress(dataProgress);
     }
 }, [progress, setProgress, dataProgress]);

 const completed = dataProgress
     ? dataProgress.dataProgress.completed: 0;
 const total = dataProgress ? dataProgress.dataProgress.total: 0;

 let value = 0;
 if (completed > 0 && total > 0) {
     value = (completed / total) * 100; //error here in place of completed and total
 }

 return (
     <ProgressBar value={value}/>
 );
```

I am querying useProgress to get data from api which is stored in dataProgress. this dataProgress has completed and total properties. i have to divide these values with 100 to get value which inturn will be passed as value prop to progress bar.

but i am encountering the error mentioned on line where i redefine value.

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: define type for value.  `let value:any = 0;`

Comment: @sojin: thanks but i still see the error after adding type to value.

Comment: @sojin: i tried adding any type to completed and total where its defined and no error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to cast it to number

```
value = Number((Number(completed) / Number(total)) * 100);
```